# Batch output md5 with corresponding file name to text file

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to output to a text file a md5 checksum of each file in a folder in this specific format:

```
checksumhash1 *NameOfFile1.ext
checksumhash2 *NameOfFile2.ext
checksumhash3 *NameOfFile3.ext
etc...
```

Here's an example of the output would need to be:

```
00c0eb18b7bfd2bf985451ae3ad5d68e *My Text File.txt
4935705ea05dabef98921b18aeeaadd3 *Another file.wmv
```

Tried the command below, and that is as close as I can get:

```
md5 -r * | tee checksum.txt
```

From there I'm lost and can't figure out how to make the output of md5 match the formatting I need. I just need that "*" in front of the file name.

Any Gurus out there? =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the output you're already getting into `sed` (or another stream editing programme) to add in the extra character needed:

```
$ md5 -r * | sed 's/ / */'
69c3da625b4570f94889c9562453d394 *file1.ext
8046313ae98a6c9f1cb2c9957cdfbe7c *file2.ext
16250bebbd00e759138d09dd0cab0cb8 *file3.ext
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e *file with space.ext
```

In this case, the `sed` command just replaces the first [space] with [space][asterisk]. You can modify the expression as required if you need it to behave differently.

Comment: I love you man! That did the trick! And another trick I learned, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `tee`, you can just redirect to a file using `>`. Now, adding the `*` requires some tricks. Here are a couple:

1. Perl

   ```
   md5 * | perl -pe 's/ / */' > checksum.txt
   ```

   That's the same as tenorkev's answer, just done in perl. The `-p` means process the input line by line, apply the script given by `-e` and print. The `s///` is the substitution operator and replaces the first space with a space followed by `*`.
2. pure shell

   ```
   md5 * | while read a b; do echo "$a *$b"; done > checksum.txt
   ```

   Here, the `while read a b` will read each line and split it on whitespace into the variables `$a` and `$b`. This means that the has will be `$a` and the rest of the line will be variable `$b`. So, printing (`echo`) `$a *$b` will give you your desired output.